# Why does Manu Smriti declare temple priests as sinful?

Tags: smriti, manu-smriti, priests

> "Physicians, temple priests, sellers of meat, and those who subsist by shop-keeping must be avoided at sacrifices offered to the gods and to the manes." (Manusmriti: 3/152)
>
> "(Food) given to a seller of Soma becomes ordure, (that given) to a physician pus and blood, but (that presented) to a temple-priest is lost, and (that given) to a usurer finds no place (in the world of the gods)." (Manusmriti: 3/180)

Comment: It's better you read scriptures with Sanskrit too. See this translation. https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199932.html

Comment: @TheDestroyer you may also post the answer :)